# Trigonometric equation obtained from Ceva

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I was working on the proof that given a triangle $ABC$ and the two points $P$ and $P'$ such that $\angle{PCA}=\angle{BCP'}$ and $\angle{CBP}=\angle{ABP'}$ then also $\angle{BAP'}=\angle{CAP}$.
To do so I applied the trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem obtaining the following:$$\frac{\sin{\angle{BAP'}}}{\sin{\angle{CAP}}}=\frac{\sin({\angle{BAC}-\angle{BAP'})}}{\sin({\angle{BAC}-\angle{CAP})}}$$
I'm unsure if this directly implies $\angle{BAP'}=\angle{CAP}$ (besides that being clearly one possible solution).

[image]

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_conjugate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your work we obtain:
$$\cos\left(\measuredangle BAP'-\measuredangle BAC+\measuredangle CAP\right)-\cos\left(\measuredangle BAP'+\measuredangle BAC-\measuredangle CAP\right)=$$
$$=\cos\left(\measuredangle BAC-\measuredangle BAP'-\measuredangle CAP\right)-\cos\left(\measuredangle BAC-\measuredangle BAP'+\measuredangle CAP\right)$$ or
$$\cos\left(\measuredangle BAP'+\measuredangle BAC-\measuredangle CAP\right)=\cos\left(\measuredangle BAC-\measuredangle BAP'+\measuredangle CAP\right)$$ or
$$\sin\measuredangle BAC\sin(\measuredangle CAP-\measuredangle BAP')=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Could you just explain me how did you derive the expression from the first line? The rest it's clear

Comment: @Spasoje Durovic I used $\sin{x}\sin{y}=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)).$

Comment: Oh I see, thank you ^_^